# How to get the 95% confidence interval in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, power-law, mle

I would like to find the 95% CI for the MLE for my parameter in a function but I have no idea how.

The given function is a power-law distribution with

f(x)=Cx^(-mu),

I calculated the MLE for mu using the bbmle package in R.

Some people on the internet say use profile likelihood to do it but I am not sure how to in R, or other methods which lead to the same results are fine too.

Much appreciate and thanks in advance!

Update:

```
load("fakedata500.Rda")
> library(stats4)
> library(bbmle)
> x<-fakedata500
> pl <- function(u){-length(x)*log(u-1)-length(x)*(u-1)*log(min(x))+u*sum(log(x))}

mle1<-mle2(pl, start=list(u=2), data=list(x))
> summary(mle1)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = pl, start = list(u = 2), data = list(x))

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
u  2.00510    0.04495  44.608 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

-2 log L: 1300.166
```

So the estimated mu is 2.00510 and I would like to get the 95% CI of it, it might look nonsense since my started mu was 2 so 2.00510 is very close to it, but I am going to apply this method to other data sets too which I havn't come across yet so really hope to find a way to do it.

Comment: Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including data and code.

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my question with some R codes. Hope that make sense.

Comment: If you're using `mle2` you should just be able to say `confint(mle1)` to get the 95% profile confidence intervals.

Comment: PS try `vignette("mle2",package="bbmle")` and search for "confint" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converted from a comment.)

If you're using `mle2` from the `bbmle` package you should just be able to say `confint(mle1)` to get the 95% profile confidence intervals.  See `?confint.mle2`, or try `vignette("mle2",package="bbmle")` and search for "confint" for more information.

Comment: Hey Ben! Do you know if there is a much more recent update on how to find confidence intervals on MLL functions? These approaches seem to be outdated and I've been scouring for months trying to find out to generate the CI for MLLs. I would appreciate any imput

Comment: If you have any time today, I would be grateful if you can take a peek at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67374974/how-to-incorporate-sigma-or-error-function-and-95-confidence-interval-in-maxi